# Authentication issue with node imap and node mail lister

Tags: node.js, email, imap, gmail-imap

I am trying to access my gmail using node imap modules.

I tried basic example of mail-listener2 as follows. I replaced with my gmail address, password and imap.gmail.com as host.However, i am facing the following error message.

> { [Error: Please log in via your web browser:
>   https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)]
>   textCode: 'ALERT', source: 'authentication' } imapDisconnected

I checked my gmail settings,enabled it for low secure applications. Enabled IMAP and verified my credentials are correct. Can someone tell me what I am missing and where am i going wrong. I tried other node-imap modules like npm-imap and imap-simple.

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener2");

var mailListener = new MailListener({
  username: "imap-username",
  password: "imap-password",
  host: "imap-host",
  port: 993, // imap port
  tls: true,
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
  searchFilter: ["UNSEEN", "FLAGGED"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved
  markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
  fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
  mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
  attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
  attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } // specify a download directory for attachments
});

mailListener.start(); // start listening

// stop listening
//mailListener.stop();

mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
  console.log("imapConnected");
});

mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
  console.log("imapDisconnected");
});

mailListener.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
  // do something with mail object including attachments
  console.log("emailParsed", mail);
  // mail processing code goes here
});

mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
  console.log(attachment.path);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and **as a quick fix** you can enable access to "less secure apps", go here:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Also you can generate an application password, but I think you must activate the two factor authentication (I'm not very sure honestly).
Hope it helps.